# Error restoring spatial database. ERROR : could not load library “/builds/postgresql-9.6.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.3.so”

Tags: postgresql, database

I am trying to restore a backup of a database. I am running postgresql-9.6.3 with postgis-2.3.3

I run the following restore command
.../myw_db new_db restore /path/to/database.backup

I get the following error message:

> ERROR: could not load library
>   “.../builds/postgresql-9.6.3/lib/rtpostgis-2.3.so”:
>   .lib64/libresolv.so.2: symbol __h_errno, version GLIBC_PRIVATE not defined in > file libc.so.6 with link time reference

I am very new at working with postgreSQL and working in the linux environment in general. I did try looking for a solution in the forums before posting.

Comment: Are you restoring on the same machine and the same software that you created the backup with? If not, how exactly did you install and configure the system?

Comment: I am restoring on a different machine. Both machine have similar environment and supposedly has the same version of postgres installed. One is a copy of the other. I personally did not do the install.

Comment: It appears PostGIS was not installed correctly. Does "copy" mean that just some files were copied? What is `myw_db`?

Comment: @CL as far as I know, one environment has been "copied" to make the other one. I tried matching up both environments and they look alike. Furthermore, I cannot find the libresolv.so.2 or libc.so.6 files in either environment. Running a search does not return those. myw_db is a web application that uses postgres as its database. I am trying to restore a backup created from the first environment to the myw application in the other one. I know the command works (previously tested)

Comment: Obviously, the libc is different. And what is `myw_db`?

Comment: Sorry I hit enter before finishing up the comment. Its updated now

Comment: It appears you have to correctly install Postgres/PostGIS.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will see what I can do.